# What does "played from your hand" actually mean?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With the Myojin cycle of cards, each of them will enter with a divinity counter if they are played from the hand. Does this mean they will enter the battlefield with a counter if they went from the hand to the battlefield, regardless of how? Or is this an old wording that in more modern days would be to cast.

[Myojin of Cleansing Fire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMyojin%20of%20Cleansing%20Fire%5d)

Comment: "played" means "played as a land or cast as a spell"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is old wording. You may check the Gatherer for the most recent wording of cards. Currently that Myojin's gatherer text says the following instead:

> Myojin of Cleansing Fire enters the battlefield with a divinity counter on it if you cast it from your hand.

"Cast from your hand" means you took it from your hand, cast it onto the stack, and then it entered the battlefield.

This is as opposed to:

- simply being put onto the battlefield without being cast (e.g. via [Champion of Rhonas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChampion%20of%20Rhonas%5d))
- being returned from your graveyard to the battlefield ([Rescue from the Underworld](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRescue%20from%20the%20Underworld%5d))
- being cast from a zone other than your own hand:

  - from the graveyard ([Havengul Lich](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHavengul%20Lich%5d))
  - from exile ([Daxos of Meletis](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDaxos%20of%20Meletis%5d))
  - from your library ([Vizier of the Menagerie](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVizier%20of%20the%20Menagerie%5d))
  - from the command zone in a game of Commander
  - from someone else's hand ([Desertion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesertion%5d) or [Sen Triplets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSen%20Triplets%5d)).

Comment: Note that the wording was not a functional change; several cards (such as Abbot of Keral Keep) still use the term "play" to refer to casting spells (because it's a blanket term that can mean either cast a spell or play a land). So even if Myojin still said "play" instead of "cast", it wouldn't refer to putting it onto the battlefield from your hand; it would only refer to casting it from your hand.